# Spartacus Skip Links are activated in second tab instead of first tab

Tags: spartacus-storefront

Please navigate to https://spartacus-demo.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com/electronics-spa/en/USD/

And press **tab**, now skip links are not getting shown.
Again press **tab**, now only skip links are started showing.

How to make it to show on first tab press.

please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first focusable element on the page is `cx-storefront`. Please change its attribute `tabindex` value from 0 to -1, then skiplinks will be first.